# SQL Date Range from current year

Tags: sql, datetime, subquery, date-range, getdate

I need to make a function in SQL on SSMS to get sums of columns pertaining to a certain date range (From 9-1 of a year until 8-31 of the next year). the issue is that each year this date range will change.

I know how to code in SQL:

```
Create View DateRangeRDView AS
Select RD1, RD2, RD3, RD4
From SomeTable
Where  PerformanceDate BETWEEN '20140901' AND '20150831'
```

but when the date range in the view needs to change to `BETWEEN '20150901' AND '20160831'`, I have to create a whole new view.

I also am aware of `GetDate()` to get current date but am unsure how to implement it to help here. Is there to do this where `GetDate()` will  be able to check if it's past `09-01` without declaring year then if it is past `09-01` `SELECT between 09-01-CURRENTYEAR and 08-31-NEXTYEAR` or it is before `09-01` `SELECT between 09-01-LASTYEAR and 08-31-CURRENTYEAR`? This will always pertain to the current year in this particular view/query

Comment: When you will change dates to 2015-2016?

Comment: Which DBMS are  you using? ("SQL" is not the name of a DBMS product - it's a query language)

Comment: Sounds like fiscal year data.  That being the case, a calendar table with the appropriate fields will simplify this task immensely.

Comment: SSMS is the DBMS, I'll edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is Sql Server then this will help I think:

```
where PerformanceDate between
  case when month(getdate())>=9 
       then cast(year(getdate()) as char(4)) + '0901' 
       else cast(year(getdate())-1 as char(4))+ '0901' end
and
  case when month(getdate())>=9 
       then cast(year(getdate())+1 as char(4)) + '0901' 
       else cast(year(getdate()) as char(4))+ '0901' end
```

Comment: This looks like it will work, thank you. Just to clarify, you have '0901' on the end too, is between not inclusive of the end value? Like is "blah between firstValue and secondValue" equivalent to "(blah >= firstValue && blah < secondValue)"?

Comment: @Davidp04, no, between includes both ends, if it not what you want then just change between on >= and < or what else you need

Comment: ok great, I'll do the same thing with '0831' on the second case. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you are using SQL Server (based on the date format and the reference to `getdate()`:

```
Create View DateRangeRDView AS
    Select RD1, RD2, RD3, RD4
    From SomeTable
    Where  PerformanceDate BETWEEN cast(datepart(year, getdate()) + '0901' as date) AND 
                                   cast(datepart(year, dateadd(year, 1, getdate())) + '0831' as date)
```